# mencoder settings for PowerPoint

Tags: unix, animation, video, video-encoding, mencoder

I have a series of jpg files that I would like to encode into video with mencoder. Currently I'm using the mpeg codec like so:

```
mencoder mf://*.jpg -mf fps=30:type=jpg -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=8000 -o video.mp4
```

...but I've been having some problems with mp4 and PowerPoint. Can someone offer a recommendation for an encoding format that plays nicely with PowerPoint and provide an example? asf maybe? I am a newbie when it comes to video encoding.

i'm using mencoder version 4.4.6